# нужно сравнить есть ли вводимый мной ключ в инпут в ассоциативном массиве, и если есть вернуть его значение

Tags: javascript

мой код выглядит так:

```
let a8 = {"b": 17, "e": 22};

function f8() {let out = document.querySelector(".out-8") 
let out = document.querySelector(".out-8")
    
    let input = document.querySelector(".i-8")

    for (let key in a8) {
        input.value += key
        if (input.value.includes(key)) out.innerHTML = a8.b
        if (input.value.includes(key)) out.innerHTML = a8.e
    }

}
```

я получаю одинаковое значение для каждого ключа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> я получаю одинаковое значение для каждого ключа

Какое значение - секрет?

---

```
out.innerHTML = Object.keys(a8).includes(input.value)? a8[input.value] : '';
```